# Bootstrap 4.3.1 Broke PopConfirm

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-popover

With the release of Bootstrap 4.3.1, PopConfirm stopped working. Whenever a PopConfirm instance is triggered, the buttons do not appear:
[image: no PopConfirm buttons]

I recreated the issue here: https://www.codeply.com/go/2BWcRgi8mc I'm using the following dependencies and updated versions, loading them in the following order:

- Bootstrap CSS 4.3.1
- jQuery 3.3.1
- popper.js 1.14.7
- Bootstrap 4.3.1
- [PopConfirm 0.4.5](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ifnot/PopConfirm/master/jquery.popconfirm.js)

When I revert back to Boostratp 4.2.1, the buttons show up just fine:
[image: PopConfirm with buttons]

PopConfirm issue: https://github.com/Ifnot/PopConfirm/issues/41

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's because in v4.3.1 we introduced a sanitizer for Tooltip and Popover templates.
By default this is what's authorized: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer

but if you need to allow button you have to do:

```
$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.Default.whiteList.button = []
```

And buttons will appear

Comment: Thanks, Johann! The example you gave references Tooltips: `$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.Default.whiteList.button = []` But if it’s for a Popover, would it be any different?

Comment: Confirming this solves it. Updated Codeply: https://www.codeply.com/go/2BWcRgi8mc. Thanks again, Johann!